# iOS connect to BLE device only once and not on every view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Im trying to understand which is the best way to connect to a BLE device. Currently I have a the connection working and pairing but i lose connection to the adapter once i change views.

```
_transporter = [BLETransporter transporterWithIdentifier:nil serviceUUIDs:serviceUUIDs];
[_transporter connectWithBlock:^(NSInputStream * _Nullable inputStream, NSOutputStream * _Nullable outputStream) {

    if ( !inputStream )
    {
        LOG( @"Could not connect to device" );
        return;
    }

    _BLEAdapter = [BLEAdapter adapterWithInputStream:inputStream outputStream:outputStream];
    [_BLEAdapter connect];
}];
```

The above code i call in viewdidload for my initial launch screen. I have a button that segues into a tableviewcontroller which will list the desired data from the device.

Every time i segue into the tableviewcontroller I added:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showTCSegue"]){
    UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    TbliewController *controller = (TbliewController *)navController.topViewController;
    controller.transporter = _transporter;
    controller.BLEAdapter = _BLEAdapter; 
  }
}
```

I also added the code below to my tableviewcontroller .h file

```
@property (nonatomic) BLETransporter* transporter;
@property (nonatomic) BLEAdapter* BLEAdapter;
```

This did not work. From my understanding it is because I need to add the strong reference type to both properties in order to share them across the view controllers. Is this correct?

I've also read about using singletons and a shared instance to execute it exactly once. Is this a better way to execute and connect the peripheral?

Every time I go back to the launch screen (main menu of the app) viewdidload gets called again and the app attempts to pair again.

Comment: I remember my BLE project with  iOS. Bit long ago but I did a class with all BLE functions and made a Singleton pattern with it duo to these problems. I had three tabs and with Singleton I had no issues - super good connection.

Comment: Do you have any good resources or examples of singleton usage. I'm having trouble understanding because of the many different implementations.

Comment: Am sorry - do not have the sources anymore - it was 3 years ago. But I remember had the same troubles. As I mentioned I implemented a class with CBManager methods and delegated this as a singleton through 3 viewcontrollers. It was Objective C - the BLE setup simple Master -> Slave. I think you could search for a simple CBManager implementation and lookup how Singleton works + delegate. It is not that hard as it sounds - hope it helps. BTW I switched to Android :)

Comment: @TobiasAlt Thank you for the info and help